# VMware licnesing for vdi and server virtualisation

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vdi

I am planning to virtualise 50 desktops as thin clients(concurrent users). Well i will need 5 servers where 3 will be used for server virtualisation and 2 for desktop virtualsiation.All the servers will be Hexa Core with 2 CPU's.I want to know the number of licenses i will be requiring for
Vmware vSphere 5 Enterprise Plus ,Vmware vCenter Server 5 Standard,Vmware Horizon Advanced edition.I am purchasing 50 TSA licenses separately.

Answer (score 0):

Call [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/in/company/office_locations/office_india) and ask them... Or call your reseller and ask them to price everything out.

Your vSphere Enterprise Plus licenses are charged per-socket. So, 10 licenses. This will be expensive. You'll need a separate vCenter Server license.

Since you need to work with a reseller for the VDI licenses, I don't think anyone here can help you with that portion.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Horizon includes the licensing for the VMware servers when you purchase seats.  You cannot/supposed to not run Servers on the VDI servers (never tried to deploy a machine).

Also, why do you need Enterprise Plus in the first place?  If sounds like you're just starting off.  I would go with a essentials plus kit.